# Framer Motion - How to make the element center in the middle of the screen? After animation

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, css-animations, framer-motion

I am trying to make an animation using **framer motion**.
The animation is doing what is supposed to do, but I am having trouble finding out how to make the initials start from the center of the page, and also the final **text**
to be centered in the middle of the page, no matter what is the screen size.

In this example, I started with a mobile-first approach.

```
import { motion, useAnimate } from 'framer-motion';

export const HeroSection: React.FC = () => {
    const [scope, animate] = useAnimate();

    return (
        <section className='flex flex-col justify-center items-center w-[90%] m-auto text-4xl md:text-5xl lg:text-6xl xl:text-7xl'>
            <div className='flex my-auto text-white font-bold '>
                <motion.div className='flex justify-center items-center'>
                    <motion.div
                        className='flex'
                        initial={{ translateX: 100 }}
                        animate={{ x: -120 }}
                        transition={{ duration: 3, delay: 2 }}
                    >
                        <h1>D</h1>
                        <motion.h1
                            className='opacity-0'
                            initial={{ display: 'hidden' }}
                            animate={{ display: 'inline', opacity: 1 }}
                            transition={{
                                ease: 'linear',
                                duration: 3,
                                delay: 5,
                            }}
                        >
                            AN
                        </motion.h1>
                    </motion.div>
                    <motion.div
                        className='flex'
                        initial={{ translateX: 0 }}
                        animate={{ x: 10 }}
                        transition={{ duration: 3, delay: 2 }}
                    >
                        <h1>J</h1>
                        <motion.h1
                            className='opacity-0'
                            initial={{ display: 'hidden' }}
                            animate={{ display: 'inline', opacity: 1 }}
                            transition={{
                                ease: 'linear',
                                duration: 3,
                                delay: 5,
                            }}
                        >
                            ECU
                        </motion.h1>
                    </motion.div>
                </motion.div>
            </div>
            <Image
                alt='down-arrow'
                src='/down-arrow.png'
                width='50'
                height='50'
                className='self-end mx-auto filter invert animate-bounce opacity-60 pb-12'
            />
        </section>
    );
};
```